# Determining whether two trees are isomorphic

Tags: algorithms, trees, binary

Is there a (probably recursive) algorithm that can be used to determine whether two not necessarily binary **ordered** (sub)trees are isomorphic or not?

Comment: Google provides a wealth of approaches ...

Comment: I can't seem to find one that's not in regards to binary trees in specific.

Comment: Look for the Maximum Isomorphic Agreement Subtree problem ...